# Escape sequence for double quotes in Sikuli's type() command not working

Tags: sikuli

I'm trying to use type() command in Sikuli 1.0.1 version, where in the string is something like this

**netsh interface ip set address name=” Wi-Fi” static 192.168.10.11 255.255.255.0 192.168.10.1**

Sikuli gives the error if try using a \ in front of the doublequotes.

Is there any way to escape this in Sikuli??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a raw string. This is done in 4 parts:

1. the letter r
2. opening single quote '
3. your string with quotes or slashes, no escaping needed
4. closing single quote '

Here is an example of what your string as a raw string would look like

```
stringWithQuotes = r'netsh interface ip set address name=” Wi-Fi” static 192.168.10.11 255.255.255.0 192.168.10.1'
type(stringWithQuotes)
```

Perhaps even better, in this situation where your string is really long, you could use paste() instead, so that you don't have to watch Sikuli type out each character--saves a bit of time:

```
paste(stringWithQuotes)
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but i'm using Command line in windows, paste won't work (CTRL+V), Anyways i got the solution to it. The first one.

Comment: Ah, right you are. Paste() uses the OS-level clipboard. In any case, I'm glad it's working!